# Why does the Markdown Sharp NuGet package lack PageDown (WMD)?

Tags: discussion, markdown, editor

I am creating a new project which will utilize the [open source project MarkdownSharp](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/). Rather than downloading and compiling the bits myself I decided to use the [MarkdownSharp NuGet package](http://nuget.org/packages/MarkdownSharp).

I realize that MarkdownSharp can be utilized for more than just web pages, but it seems strange given Stack Overflow's focus that there isn't a NuGet package including [Stack Exchange's WMD project PageDown](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/).

Are there any plans to create an additional package or to modify the current package?

Comment: Note that the Stack Exchange WMD project (renamed PageDown) [is on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/).

Comment: @TimStone thanks didn't realize that, which bolsters the argument for including PageDown in a NuGet package.

Comment: I am not aware of a Nuget package that we've created of MD#.

Comment: Besides that, it would make zero sense to include Pagedown/WMD in that package, even if we did make it.

Comment: @balpha why does it make zero sense? Call it Markdown Sharp for MVC.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to confirm what I said in the comments: **We did not create that package**. I don't know who did, but it was none of us. Our official version of MarkdownSharp [is on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/), and there *only*.

Comment: That is very good to know and just for further clarification the Stack Overflow "supported" version of Page Down is at: http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/?

Comment: Yep, that's it.

Comment: It says Jeff Atwood in the package description, so...

Comment: @John ... so...?

Comment: Atwood is Stackoverflow's co-founder, so it's certainly close to it.

Comment: @John Jeff is listed as author, not package owner, so I don't understand what this has to do with the question (or my answer).

Comment: @balpha True, I didn't notice the distinction.